# Passing an attribute from a resource with count [0 or 1] defined to a module - possible?

Tags: terraform

Terraform 0.12.13, azurerm provider 1.35

Some background:  I have a set of Azure App Services, hosted on an App Service Plan, in a Resource Group, in an Azure location.  I now need to duplicate this stack in a different Azure location and add some additional resources like Traffic Managers and CNAMEs and whatnot in order to implement high availability.  Architecturally we have Primary resources, and then a smaller subset of Secondary resources in the secondary region (not everything needs to be duplicated).  Not every deployment will require high availability, so I need to be able to instantiate or not instantiate the Secondaries at run-time.

Because I was trying to be a good software engineer, I created modules to instantiate most of this stuff - one for the app services, one for the app service plan, one for the traffic managers, and so on.

The problem I have now is that I'm using the old count + ternary operator trick to control whether the secondary resources get created, and this is breaking because 1) count isn't allowed as a module meta-argument yet and 2) I can't figure out how to pass exported attributes from a resource controlled by the count meta-argument to a module as an input variable.

The following code may make this clearer.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "appservices_secondary" {
  name     = "foo-services-ca-${local.secondary_release_stage_name}-${var.pipeline}-rg"
  location = local.secondary_location

  count = var.enable_high_availability ? 1 : 0
}

# Create the app service plan to host the secondary app services
module "plan_secondary" {
  source                     = "./app_service_plan"
  release_stage_name         = local.secondary_release_stage_name

  # HERE'S THE PROBLEMATIC LINE
  appsvc_resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.appservices_secondary[0].name

  location                   = local.secondary_location
  pipeline                   = var.pipeline
}
```

If count resolves to 1 (`var.enable_high_availability = true`) then everything's fine.
If count resolves to 0 (`var.enable_high_availability = false`) then `terraform plan` fails:

```
Error: Invalid index

  on .terraform\modules\services\secondary.tf line 25, in module "plan_secondary":
  25:   appsvc_resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.appservices_secondary[0].name
    |----------------
    | azurerm_resource_group.appservices_secondary is empty tuple

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

If I change the input variable value to `azurerm_resource_group.appservices_secondary.name` then it won't pass `terraform validate` because it recognizes that it needs `[count.index]`.

Is there a simple way to resolve this?  I'm increasingly thinking this is a design problem and I should have built the modules with count = [1..2] rather than count = 1 (primary) and count = [0 || 1] (secondary) but that will require me to rewrite all the modules and I'd like to avoid that if there's some clever workaround.

Comment: Do you have a default value that will work as an input if `azurerm_resource_group.appservices_secondary` is not applied? If yes, I can provide a solution. If not, this is likely not possible.

Comment: I think I can work with that - please let me know what you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to resolve this you can use a conditional expression for `appsvc_resource_group_name` to provide some alternative value to use when the `azurerm_resource_group.appservices_secondary` resource has `count = 0`:

```
  appsvc_resource_group_name = length(azurerm_resource_group.appservices_secondary) > 0 ? azurerm_resource_group.appservices_secondary[0].name : "default-value"
```

It looks like this other module is not useful in situations where high availability is disabled. In that case, you might want to define the variable as being optional with a default of `null` so that you can recognize when it isn't set in the module:

```
variable "appsvc_resource_group_name" {
  type    = string
  default = null
}
```

Elsewhere in the configuration you can test `var.appsvc_resource_group_name != null` to see if it's enabled.

---

When following [the module composition patterns](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/composition.html) I'd likely instead build this as two modules, using one of the following two strategies:

- One module for building a "normal" (non-HA) stack and another module for building a HA stack, and then choose which one to use in the root module of each configuration depending on whether a particular configuration needs the normal or HA mode.
- Alternatively, if the HA stack is always a superset of the "normal" stack, have one module for the normal stack, and then another module that consumes the outputs of the first and describes the extended resources needed for HA mode.

Here's an example of the second of those approaches, just to illustrate what I mean by it:

```
module "primary_example" {
  source = "./primary_example"

  # whatever arguments are needed
}

module "secondary_example" {
  source = "./secondary_example"

  # Make sure the primary module exports as outputs all of the
  # values required to extend to HA mode, and then just pass
  # that whole object through to secondary.
  primary = module.primary_example
}
```

In a configuration that doesn't need HA mode you can then omit `module "secondary_example"`.

The module composition patterns are about decomposing the configuration into small pieces that describe one self-contained capability and then letting the root module select from those capabilities whatever subset of them are relevant and connecting them in a suitable way.

In this case, I'm treating non-HA infrastructure as one capability and then HA extensions to that infrastructure as a second capability that depends on the first, connecting them together in a dependency inversion style so that the HA extensions can just assume that a non-HA deployment already exists and that information about it will be passed in by its caller.

Comment: This is functionally equivalent to what I was going to post as an answer, so go ahead and use this one.

Comment: I eventually figured out the conditional part, but the rest of this answer is actually more valuable than the solution to my original problem.  Thanks!